# Algorithm/optimization for area minimizing hull

Tags: optimization, cluster-analysis

Assuming I have several points in a 2D plane.
I now want to create a hull that covers all points. The shape of that hull should be somehow weighted by the distance/closeness of the points, i.e., outsiders must be connected to the rest of the points by a narrow link (see [target state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj8up.jpg)).
[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwzkX.jpg) also shows a hull that is covering all points, however, does not narrow down the link to the three outliers.
I also do not want an alpha-shape or convex hull because that would not obfuscate the location of my points, because I can retrieve the location from the vertices.

Is there any area of algorithms/optimizations that covers this kind of problem?

Comment: Seems like you want a minimum spanning tree? That has no area, but is the minimum-length way of connecting all points in a cluster.

Comment: @templatetypedef I don't think that's what I want. In the end, I want the coordinates of the covering hull such that I can check if a new point in the plan is located within the hull or measure the distance to the hull if the point is outside.